# new and fresh ideas with stack exchange dataset

Tags: data-mining, bigdata, dataset

I'm a new bee for data analysis . i need to work on a research project in big data analysis. first of all i search for a dataset and i found interest in s[tack exchange  data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange). however i browse for researches i found a lot .And whatever i thought about a idea based on this dataset , its already done by someone else . 
please help me out with a new and useful idea for my research .

Answer (score 2):

It might help to have a bit more information on what you want to do, but have a look at [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com) - it's a regular big data science competition, all of the data sets are huge and [available for download](https://www.kaggle.com).

There's also some [smaller datasets made available by Tableau](https://public.tableau.com/s/resources).

Hope that give you some inspiration!